# returning null values as something else from a query

Tags: sql, odbc

```
SELECT TEST_CODE, TEST_MDL FROM TEST WHERE TEST_CODE LIKE 'DW-LI' 
                OR TEST_CODE LIKE 'DW-BE'
                OR TEST_CODE LIKE 'DW-SC'
                OR TEST_CODE LIKE 'DW-V'
                OR TEST_CODE LIKE 'DW-CR'
                OR TEST_CODE LIKE 'DW-CO';
```

I have this query and I need to write the results to an excel file. I can do that, however when the a field is null I need the query to return null or something else instead of just a blank.

I tried doing something like this:

```
SELECT TEST_CODE, TEST_MDL,
   ISNULL(TEST_MDL),'null')'
   FROM TEST;
```

That didn't work. Any suggestions?
I am running the query from a program using vb.net and also connecting as odbc, because of some limitations. I hope this helps.
Thanks!

Comment: I tried it, but that did not work @FlashThunder

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT TEST_CODE, TEST_MDL,
    CONVERT(varchar(20),ISNULL(TEST_MDL,'null')) 
   FROM TEST;
```

Comment: Can you expand on this a little - perhaps explain what it does?

Comment: I asume TEST_MDL is a number, and maybe 0 is a valid value. That is the reason I don't like previous answer from user3616953.
As you can't insert a text -'null' in this case- in a number column, I need to convert result column in text

Comment: TEST_MDL is a number. It works at http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/f48c3/8 nut not in my program, I do not understand. @Horaciux

Comment: I meant can you expand _the answer_

Comment: @user3276838 you insert blank space, not null values, and you define columns as varchar not number (int, ie).http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/cb906/1

Answer (score 0):

Use the function COALESCE to substitute real values for nulls:

```
SELECT TEST_CODE, coalesce(TEST_MDL,0) 
    FROM TEST;
```

The COALESCE function takes one or more values as arguments. The function returns the first non-null value in the list. In the solution, the value of TEST_MDL is returned whenever TEST_MDL  is not null. Otherwise, a zero is returned.